# Dynamically add functions to a class definition

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, prototype

I have a library which I'm transitioning to use ES2015 syntax and distribute as an ES module.

It exposes a class, many of the members of which are constructed dynamically. Massively simplified, its structure is like this:

```
class Utils {
    // ...
}

extraFuncs.forEach(funcName => Utils.prototype[funcName] = makeFunc(funcName));
export default Utils;
```

(Actual code is [here](https://github.com/stevage/mapbox-gl-utils/blob/master/src/index.js#L721)).

Is there a way to achieve this dynamic creation of methods without manipulating the prototype?

Adding functions directly to the class doesn't seem to achieve anything. And using a spread operator to incorporate an object doesn't seem to work either.

(One of my motivations here is passing a particular lint rule that complains about what I'm doing.)

Comment: Which lint rule is it?

Comment: A custom company-internal one I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this dynamic creation of methods without manipulating the prototype?

No. Dynamic creation of methods by definition means extending the prototype (apart from `evil` approaches).

Disable that linter rule.

Comment: Evil meaning, `eval`? :)